# Docker Hub to VPS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

Note: I am a .NET Developer that is dabbling in DevOps. I want to learn.

**Current Situation:**

I have my .NET Core project dockerised. It sits [on GitHub](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity) and is Open Source. Using Travis CI; as soon as I check some code into the GitHub repository, Travis CI builds a fresh docker image and pushes it [to Docker Hub](https://cloud.docker.com/u/bejebeje/repository/docker/bejebeje/identity) with two tags `$BUILD_NUMBER` and `latest`.

I have an Ubuntu VPS where I plan on running my dockerised applications.

**Question:**

Once the images are uploaded to Docker Hub (i.e. travis has finished the steps inside .travis.yml), how can I get those latest images to automatically run on my VPS?

This is where I am stuck.

I understand that once the docker containers are running on my VPS, I have to [set up nginx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as proxy ...etc, so I'm OK with that. I am just stuck on getting the latest docker image running on my VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One typical solution is to add a deployment task to your Travis CI pipeline.  This task may, for example, run a command on your Ubuntu VPS to pull and run the `:latest` image.  You could use any number of techniques to accomplish this: a CM tool like Ansible or Chef, a Bash script or simply SSH.

Travis CI documentation has some information on deployment providers: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/